# Windows 8 Time Changes Constantly

Tags: windows, clock

On Windows 8, the timezone is correct and it's connected to the internet. Even so, after reboot it changes the time even though the settings are correct. How can I fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to synchronize the system clock with a time server.

Go to Adjust the date, and search in the `Internet Time` tab the option  `Synchronize with an Internet time server`.

Comment: The weird part is< I don't have the Internet Time tab. I just have Additional Clocks and Date and Time. How do I get "Internet Time" tab?

Comment: Well, thats because the Internet Time feature is only there in workgroup environments, and it looks like your system is member of a domain.

Comment: How can I get into a workgroup environment? I've read that just now, too.

Comment: It's also telling me that I'm not an administrator... when I clearly am.

Comment: Start -> Control Panel ->  System -> Look for Computer Name tab (or Name ... and etc Configuration) -> Look for Change button -> You should see some options to change ID or join to a domain. Select WORKGROUP

Comment: Well, look for C:\Windows\System32\control.exe, and execute that "as Administrator" (right click), but i thik that's redundant. Probably you are from admins group.

Comment: So by joining or creating a workgroup, nothing on my desktop or login details will be changed or deleted, right? No files, settings, etc.

Comment: @user280902 You need to know why you are in a domain. Computers on workplace networks are usually part of a domain. With an user account on the domain, you can log in to any computer on the domain. In a workgroup , tipicaly a home network, each computer has its own set of user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I found that my clock was already synchronized by default with time.windows.com. I found that the time zone was incorrect.  I live in South Africa and the time zone was set on Central Time on my computer.

After clicking on the Change date and time settings... I was directed to the Date and Time tab in the Date and Time window.  I went to the Change time zone... button and chose the Harare, Pretoria time zone.  This fixed my problem and I hope that it will fix your's as well :)